# How long do editor decisions take at Science/Nature?

Tags: journals, peer-review, science

What does the distribution of wait times for a editor decision look like for a manuscript submitted to Science or Nature?

(You are not allowed to say "Gamma" unless you give a shape and scale parameter)

Comment: In my experience rejection is quite rapid - 48 hours or so. No news is good news?

Comment: Exponential? ;)

Comment: @Fomite so you still said gamma with just 1 parameter... What is the other?

Answer (score 3):

Usually they decide in less than a week after the initial submission. Either rejection or sending it out for review.
Sometimes they are more busy. For our last submission the decision took 25 days for which the editor apologized.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences with these journals have not been this positive. It's true that editorial rejections can be very rapid based on scope and perceived 'gee whiz' factor. I've had Nature hold up papers for months and been forced out by a singe powerful reviewer with advice to publish the paper in another highly ranked (but not glamour mag) journal. These are very political journals.